# onLocationChanged never called?

Tags: android, locationmanager, android-location

I am using exact code form [developer.android.com/](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) but it seems to not work 100%, I was same code yesterday and it worked. I have all permissions that are required.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

I had added `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` permission just in case first doesn't work.

**Code:**

```
Log.i("DEV", "LocationManager");
// Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

Log.i("DEV", "LocationListener");
// Define a listener that responds to location updates
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {Log.i("DEV", "onLocationChanged");}

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {Log.i("DEV", "onStatusChanged");}

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {Log.i("DEV", "onProviderEnabled");}

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {Log.i("DEV", "onProviderDisabled");}
};

Log.i("DEV", "Register listener");
// Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

I have turned on mobile data or wifi always same **log output**:

```
09-28 20:06:56.816  21408-21408/smst.dev.mav.com I/DEV﹕ LocationManager
09-28 20:06:56.826  21408-21408/smst.dev.mav.com I/DEV﹕ LocationListener
09-28 20:06:56.826  21408-21408/smst.dev.mav.com I/DEV﹕ Register listener
09-28 20:06:56.826  21408-21408/smst.dev.mav.com I/DEV﹕ onProviderDisabled
```

Thanks!

Comment: Although it is very late but I hope this comment can help someone else, look at this link: http://www.lengrand.fr/2013/10/onlocationchanged-is-never-called-on-android

Answer (score 1):

Android has two location providers - GPS and Coarse(Network) location.
you need to enable both separately in order to use each one.
take a look here:

[image]

you can check if each of them is enabled by using:
    
    `locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);`